# MVC redirect to previous page (exclude not httppost action)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have three action on controller

```
public ActionResult Index() {}
public ActionResult Insert() {}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert() {
     //some insert code
     redirect to where you come from but exclude Insert page
}
```

and other controller

```
public ActionResult Example() {}
```

i am going to Insert page from Index or maybe from Example then submit the form to HttpPost action. i am trying redirect to Index page or Example page (im trying to find i came from which page). how can i achieve that (UrlReferrer is redirect to Insert page)

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index")` ?

Comment: oh sorry Index is on different controller

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index","YourControllerName")`

Comment: my last edit i think describe my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is ,keep track of where the request comes from. There are multiple ways to do it. Here is one

In your `insert` GET action method, you can read the `UrlReferrer` value and pass that to the view, where you will keep that inside a hidden input inside the form.  When the form is submitted, you can read this in your HttpPost action method and do a redirect to that.

```
public ActionResult Insert()
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
    return View(new InsertVm());
}
```

and in your form

```
@model InsertVm 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Users"))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewBag.ReturnUrl" />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.EmailAddress)
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

Now in your `Insert` HttpPost action, add a parameter with the same name as your hidden input

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert(InsertVm model,string returnUrl)
{
    // to do : Save data

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    //fall back
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

Comment: i found a way. on insert action added referrer to session then read on httppost. anyway i think you are close too.

Comment: Session keeps it around a lot longer. ViewBag makes more sense here IMO.

Comment: True. Another option is to have a property in your view model and use that. I would prefer that than ViewModel :)